# Zeller's congruence and cal command

Tags: history, cal

According to [Zeller's Congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence), the day of 29 Feb, 1600 is Tuesday. However, the cal command shows it as Friday.Is there a bug in cal's code or a limit on the range of years which Zeller's congruence can predict the day for.

Comment: Please give a reference and futher details on Zeller's congruence. We are too lazy to run off googling (or binging, or whatever might be your fancy) for it.

Comment: @vishnuvp I added a link to the Wikipedia article, as well as the history tag, since the reason cal does what it does is explained in a 40-year-old man page. Hope that's OK.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick that's absolutely fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most locales, `cal` uses the version of the Gregorian calendar used by Britain and its colonies, which includes an [11-day discontinuity in September, 1752](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/apgb/Geo2/24/23/contents). As the [V7 man page](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/man/man1/cal.1) says:

> The calendar
>   produced is that for England and her colonies.
>
> Try September 1752.

So dates before this time may not fall on the weekdays one might expect from extrapolating a modern calendar.

If you're using `gcal`, you can give it the [`--gregorian-reform`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/manual/gcal.html#index-Period-of-Gregorian-Reformation_002c-set) option to set the date and duration of the discontinuity.